# Relative div with background and vertical centered text

Tags: html, css

I need to make div with 90% of height screen with image background and vertical centered text inside.

I use double div.

For 90% height I use 
    min-height: 90vh;

My full html code looks like:

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <div class="three">
            <h1>Заголовок</h1>
            <p>пилорама текст</p>
                       <p> Много другого текста.</p>
           <p> Много другого текста.</p>
           <p> Много другого текста.</p>
           <p> Много другого текста.</p>
           <p> Много другого текста.</p>
                    <h1>Заголовок</h1>
            <p>пилорама текст</p>
                       <p> Много другого текста.</p>
           <p> Много другого текста.</p>
           <p> Много другого текста.</p>
           <p> Много другого текста.</p>
           <p> Много другого текста.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My css file looks like:

```
.one {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  min-height: 90vh;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('1501.jpg');

}

.two{
    background-image: url('post.png');
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

How it looks together you can see here on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gumbert/ddkd1bs9/3/

How can I stretch second background image and vertical centered text?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by defining your wrapping container `one` as position relative and the inner divs as absolute. 
With the help of `margin: auto` you can then center absolute positioned block elements. Changes to your fiddle would be like this:

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <div class="content">
            ....
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>

.one {
     // ...
     position: relative;
}

.two{
    // ...
    position:absolute;
}

.content {
     display:table;
     width:100%;
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     bottom:0;
     margin-top:auto;
     margin-bottom:auto;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ddkd1bs9/11/

Comment: Looks good. Thanks. But how I can horisontally centered .content? `align: center` and `text-align: center` doesn't work...

Comment: i edited my answer and posted the correct fiddle. i forgot the `width:100%` in `.content` in the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. That's really good! But just onother one thing. How can I limit div `.content` minimal height? [link to pic](http://prntscr.com/53djqb) text should always be inside

Comment: you mean you want to limit the maximum height? you can just use `overflow: hidden` in your `.two`. If my answer works regarding your original question, would be happy if you mark at as accepted. Welcome to Stack Overflow btw. ;)

Comment: Not quite. I mean if text bigger than background, height div = height of text. The entire text should always be visible. Thanks for welcome ;)

Comment: You mean your `.two` should  expand  regarding the height of your Texts in `.content` then we have to change the markup and most of the css because absolute positioned elements never affect dimensions of their parent relative positioned elements. Multiple ways to do it though but a little bit too much for the comment section

Answer (score 0):

2 things you can probaly do:

Add this for the picture

`min-height: 100%;
max-height: 100%;`

OR add repeat so it will repeat that picture over the width and height you want it too.

 `background-image: url('post.png') repeat;`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified and trimmed down solution that uses multiple backgrounds and transforms: http://jsfiddle.net/fkdpr10v/.

HTML:

```
<div id = "main">
    <div>
        <h1>Заголовок</h1>
        <p>текст</p>
        <p>Много другого текста.</p>
        <p>Много другого текста.</p>
        <p>Много другого текста.</p>
        <p>Много другого текста.</p>
        <p>Много другого текста.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<p>More text below</p>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: green;
}

#main {
    position: relative
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    height: 90vh;
    min-height: 90vh;
    background: url('https://imgurhd.ru/i/25s4.png'), 
                url('https://imgurhd.ru/i/25s3.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
}

#main > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: mh, i just commented this on another answer, so to stay consistent: don't use an elements `id` as css selector.

Comment: @Alrazah why? It is perfectly acceptable. There was some post how using a tag vs  class vs id is faster. That author was proven wrong the last I saw

Comment: and don't you think using `transform` for plain positioning is a little bit over the top? it's basically for animations using hardware acceleration right?. actually, this could be worth a question :)

Comment: @Ryan well first of all ids have to be unique. that alone would be reason enough for me at least. your markup as well as your css would explode in larger projects if you consistently use ids instead of classes. another reason for me would be, that ids are used mostly to select a specific element via javascript or similar, so having this in mind you know on first sight if an html element has an id it serves a special purpose while having a class or multiple classes is just for layouting. (of course this is no rule, but i think more or less better practice)

Comment: @Alrazah.  First, by definition, classes represent categories to which multiple elements belong.  Thus, for distinct sections using `id` attribute is more appropriate.  In CSS, id references have a higher specificity.  Also, if HTML5 is relied upon, then the `main` tag could be employed here instead of using `<div id = "main">`.  Next, the width and height of the inner div is not explicitly set or known.  Using `translateX()` and `translateY()` transforms is the only way to vertically and horizontally center an absolute block.

Comment: Well, if you want to stick to the "definition" of css classes and only use them for multiple elements and not specific ones, why don't you use inline styles instead of ids? And about the translate thing, take a look at my answer. there the absolute positioned element is vertically and horizontally centered without using `transform`.

Comment: Using inline styles is generally a bad practice.  Creating and maintaining this type of code is just a nightmare.  All in all, if you have a distinct HTML block, then assign an id to it.  If you would like to apply same styles to multiple elements, then assign classes to them.  Better yet, if possible, use markup and relationships among the elements when specifying selectors.  Lastly, in your code you are not centering the block, but via `text-align: center` you are centering content, which is within the block: http://jsfiddle.net/q31gzw2j/.  Overall, you've used more HTML and CSS code.

Comment: @Alrazah please review the answer, I am not the author. Based on the details by OP, using an `id` for `class='one'` is a fine solution. I don't know Russian (?), so maybe the context would help some. I doubt `<main>` should be used here, unless the content is the main content of the page.

Comment: The Russian text used in this example is just a filler.  It simply says "Heading" and "A lot of other text."